# How can i upload a file (type="file") using Selenium WebDriver in Ruby

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

How can I upload a file with Selenium WebDriver,using Ruby. Here is what I am doing. However no keys are being sent:

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "upload_file").clear

@driver.find_element(:id, "upload_file").send_keys ("/Users/mrunal/Documents/AboutStacks.pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a

```
@driver.find_element(:id, "upload_file").click
```

If not working try using the `send_keys` command two times.

If nothing works update to the latest selenium version (I read there are problems with the newest firefox version and sendkeys)